# How to store tools in teamcity without running build?

Tags: teamcity

Is there a possibility to store stuff (maven, dependencies docs, etc) without running a build and get them as dependencies for other workflows?

In Anthill it's called code-station if it's helps.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question. In TeamCity, there are artifacts that the build configration can expose. Maven, as a tool, is a configuration but not an artifact; a build step doesn't produce "maven" as an artifact. The dependencies, in case of Maven builds, are coming from a Maven repository which is configured in your settings. So once you run a build configuration that defines an artifact that is produced as a result from a Maven build, then this artifact can be used by the other build configuration in the build chain, yes.

Comment: for example: I want to clean my agent machine before build process starts and bring from some storage tools which needed for build to be created. It can be maven, encryption tools, localization\translation tools etc... The question is if I can store data in TeamCity without running flows\jobs and get it as a dependency for other workflows.

Comment: Maybe running the build in Docker containers would actually solve the task for you? Sounds like you are looking for a provisioning solution that prepares the environment.